# "ipa build" passes from the command line but fails on Jenkins (Shenzhen Xcode iOS app)

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, jenkins, ipa

I am building a MyApp.ipa from MyApp.xcodeproj via commad line and the build is successfull. I am using the [Shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) ruby gem to build the app from command line. However the build is failing in Jenkins with the following errors:

```
*** error: Couldn't codesign /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData///////MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: codesign failed with exit code 1
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

The following build commands failed:

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData///////MyApp.app
```

I suspect the error is related to the project signing. Currently I am signing it via command line with [XSigning](https://github.com/phynet/XSigning) and it builds successfully from the command line on the local MacOS machine. However when I am running the exact same commands via Jenkins it fails.

Please help.

Comment: I see you already make it work. Would you please share your solution and the detailed steps to reproduce? I already unlocked my keychain but I'm not sure what should I put in the path variable

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your Jenkins build runs on the same machine that you tested through command line:

`codesign` requires the Provisioning Profiles to sign the IPA. By default, these are located here `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`.

As you can see, the `~` is the user's home directory, i.e `/Users/user_name_here/`. The default permissions on that directory usually only allow access to that user only.

Jenkins runs by default as `jenkins` user. You need to make sure that your `jenkins` user has access to the directory where the provisioning profiles are. Or else, move the provisioning profiles to another location that `jenkins` user has access to, and modify your build tool to look for them there.

If your Jenkins master/slave node is not on the same Mac machine as you tested with command line, then you will have to manually copy the provisioning files to that machine too

Comment: My Jenkins is configured as admin. The Mac machine is actualy is the slave. Resolved the issue by updating the $path and unlocking the keychain. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this: Move the certs/keys you're trying to sign with from "login" to "System" in Keychain Access. You won't need to keep unlocking the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that there is some problem with your `$path` or another environment variable (which is a common problem, looking like yours).

Jenkins executes its jobs in a "clean" environment (whithout any environment variable).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Updated the path, still was failing though. Thinking it is due to the key-chain was locked. Unlocked it with "security unlock-keychain ...". Restarted the build now. Hopefully will pass.

Comment: Passed finally, after updating the path and unlocking the keychain. Thanks.

Comment: You should answer your own question with the full solution, and accept it (after 2 days).